# Using Html helpers in an index page that is not in view folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I am developing a MVC single page application. My index page is in my root folder and I need to use Html Helpers like Html.BeginForm , Html.AntiForgeryToken Html.LabelFor etc...

When I try to use the helpers I get the following message : System.Web.WebPages.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for LabelFor and no extension method LabelFor accepting a first argument of type... same with BeginForm and AntiForgeryToken.

I have the following reference in my project System.Web.Helpers.

Can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

You  probably break the default webconfig file in Views Folder. Create a new mvc4  project and copy its webconfig file located in Views Folder ,  and set

```
  key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" to  key="webpages:Enabled" value="true"
```

in appSettings then clean and rebuild the project and finally restart the visual studio.  that is all.